# AngularJS - call controller method after animation is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button and a hidden div. When I click the button, the div will expand in width. This is my HTML so far:

```
<div ng-controller="PageController">
   <button ng-click="togglePage()>Show Details</div>
   <div class="page-slide-animation" ng-show="page">
   </div>
</div>
```

My controller provides the following method:

```
$scope.togglePage= function() {
    $scope.page = !$scope.page;
};
```

And this is my animation:

```
app.animation('.page-slide-animation', [function() {
    return {
        beforeAddClass : function(element, className, done) {
            if(className == 'ng-hide') {
                jQuery(element).animate({width: 'toggle'}, function() {
                    done();
                });
            }
        },
        removeClass : function(element, className, done) {
            if(className == 'ng-hide') {
                jQuery(element).animate({width: 'toggle'}, function() {
                    done();
                });
            }
        }
    };
}]);
```

This works fine so far. What I would need to do is to call a controller method in `PageController` after the animation has finished. What is the best way to do this (inject a service to the animation, using a timeout in the controller,..)?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to emit an event with $rootScope.$emit and catch it into the controller.

Comment: Something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/n9evtryd/1/

Clicking on the button you activate a function which is called after 2 seconds. This function calls a service which emit an event catched by another controller

Comment: Does this work with animations as well? Or do I have to pass the service into the animation and use it there?

Comment: If you intend to use it directly in the animation, then yes, you have to inject it in. For istance:
app.animation('.page-slide-animation', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope)

Answer (score 0):

Try using $scope.$emit and catch this in controller using $scope.$on